# Такой способ создания объектов одинаковый?

Tags: javascript

```js
function Rabbit(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var rabbit = new Rabbit("Кроль");
console.log(rabbit);
```

```js
function Rabbit(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var rabbit = new Rabbit("Кроль");


var rabbit2 = new rabbit.constructor("Крольчиха");
console.log(rabbit2);
```

1. Это происходит из-за того что prototype хранится значение constructor который получает ссылку на объект ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для ответа достаточно проверить, что хранится в свойстве `constructor`

```js
function Rabbit(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var rabbit = new Rabbit("Кроль");

console.log(rabbit.constructor === Rabbit);
```

Так как это та же самая функция, различий при вызове не будет.

---

Однако, так как `constructor` это **обычное свойство** - оно может быть переписано в любом месте и результаты станут отличаться.